# Tabularx, Footnotes and how to continue them afterwards

Tags: footnotes, tabularx

So I am trying to give a brief summary of things in a `tabularx` within a table. As I am providing data I obviously like to give footnotes as to where I have got this data from.

Currently I am using `\footnotemark[*number of the mark*]` next to the data within the table and `\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{asdf}` for every source after the table.

My problems with this solution are as follows:

- the actual footnotes are on the next site
- the counter does not increase. So if i use a footnote on the next page I have 2 times footnote 1 (one from the table on from the next page)

My desired solution should:

- work from within a `tabularx` (within a table)
- (nice to have) show the footnotes on the same page
- and actually increase the counter so that the next time I use `\footnote{}`, it does not use the same numbers as the one used in  the table
- be "automatic" as I will probably have some more tables with similar data within my paper.

---

#### Edit

An example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\center
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X X X X}
\textbf{H1} & \textbf{H2} & \textbf{H3} & \textbf{H4} & \textbf{H5}
\tabularnewline
\hline
Category  & *Data1*\footnotemark[1]  & *Data5*\footnotemark[2] & *Data7*\footnotemark[3]  & Unit
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{caption}
\label{tab_asdf}
\end{table}

\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{text1} 
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{text2}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{text3} 
\lipsum[1-3]
text on the next page\footnote{footnote that should be 10 but is 1 again}
\end{document}
```

#### Edit 2

Changing the table from `[H]` to `[htb]` solved the problem of the footnotes being on the next site. The footnote on the next site still starts with 1 again. But as far as I understood in IEEE format the next should be 10.

#### Edit 3

I changed the Code to look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{table}[H]
\center
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X X X X}
\textbf{H1} & \textbf{H2} & \textbf{H3} & \textbf{H4} & \textbf{H5}
\tabularnewline
\hline
Category  & *Data1*\tnote{1}  & *Data5*\tnote{2} & *Data7*\tnote{3}  & Unit
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{caption}
\label{tab_asdf}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] note1
\item [2] note2
\item [3] note3
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\lipsum[1-3]
text on the next page\footnote{footnote that should be 10 but is 1 again}
\end{document}
```

I chose the `[H]` over the other option as I don't want the table to "disturb" the next chapter. The Table and the Notes seem to work just fine.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please consider to share a compileable minimal working example that illustrates your issue. Best regards

Comment: @user1146332 thank you, i added the code i have troubles with

Comment: Note that foot notes generally does not belong in tables. There they are instead called table notes and normally comes at the end of the table. Have a look at the `threeparttable` package or my extention of it `threeparttablex`.

Comment: Also note the it is not recommended to use the `[H]` placement. This is a tempting hole that many new LaTeX users tend to dig themselfs into. Use `[htp]` or `[htbp]` instead. Yes it will no longer come **right here** but instead **here about** and that is what you want in order to avoid big blank spots in your document.

Comment: Thirdly the code you provided is not a MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) we cannot copy a sniplet like this and test your code as is. We have to guess the documentclass and relevant preamble. So please help us help you.

Comment: @daleif 

1) thank you for the hint regarding table notes

2) previously it put the table on the end of the document( a few pages down) but i will try your options; Edit: that solved the problem of the footnotes being on the next page

3) i read the thread you linked, and i can tell you i d have to guess what kind of documentclass that would be, as i am using the setup provided by my university, and i have no clue what class that is as they have obviously generated their own.

Comment: WHat you post here should also work with the `article` or `book` class plus a suitable relevant preamble.